# index of first greater than during two array comparison

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays threshold and values.

```
threshold=[10 22 97]  
values=[99 23 77 11 8 10]
```

I want to output idx such that threshold(idx-1)`<`values(i)`<=`threshold(idx). That is for the above example output will be

```
output=[4 3 3 2 1 1]
```

The naive code that can produce above output will be

```
output=ones(1,length(values))*(length(values)+1); 
for i=1:length(values)  
  for j=1:length(threshold)  
    if(values(i)>threshold(j))  
       output(i)=j;
    end  
  end  
end
```

Is there a simple way of doing it. I want to avoid loops.

Comment: Also the inner loop with j, can be replaced with find function. That is, find(threshold>values(i),1,'first');

Comment: Why do you want to avoid loops ?  You want a simple way, yet you already have a naive way.  What is the desired difference between a naive way and a simple way ?

Comment: The matrix is really huge. The for loop is very very slow.

Comment: Your `values` isn't sorted...I suppose that is a typo?

Comment: I want a matlab friendly code that is faster.

Comment: The values are unsorted. Sorting affects the functionality of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) command, with a slight adjustment of `threshold` array

```
>> threshold=[-inf 10 22 97 inf];
>> values=[99 23 77 11 8 10]; 
>> [~, output] = histc( values, threshold+.1 )
output =

 4     3     3     2     1     1
```

The modification of `threshold` is due to "less-than"/"less-than-equal" type of comparison for bin boundary decisions.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis yes... I was surprised to see your answer - I honestly thought you got ahead of me and I was about to delete my answer...

Comment: seems my answer is wrong in the context of non-sorted `values`...I'll delete mine and drink some coffee :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis please do not delete your answer. it is a good example of comparison using `bsxfun`.

Comment: @Shai: well, if you insist.

Answer (score 2):

No loops often means you'll gain speed by increasing peak memory. Try this:

```
threshold = [10 22 97];
values    = [99 23 77 11 8 10];

%// Do ALL comparisons
A = sum(bsxfun(@gt, values.', threshold));

%// Find the indices and the ones before 
R = max(1, [A; A-1]);

%// The array you want
R(:).'
```

If you run out of memory, just use the loop, but then with a `find` replacing the inner loop.

Loops aren't all that bad, you know (if you have MATLAB > R2008). In theory, the solution above shouldn't even be faster than a loop with `find`, but oh well...profiling is key :)